# Compare strings between an Editor and objects in an Observablecollection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an `Observablecollection` of objects which have a `Note` property. In an `Editor` I insert some text and look for the elements inside the `Observable` that have in the `Note` property that part of the text I insert but the exception that comes out is this:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

```
List<HumorDiary> resultSearch { get; set; } = new List<HumorDiary>();



private void AvviaRicerca_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       resultSearch = control.controlDiary.Where(x => x.Nota.ToUpper().Contains(TestoSearch.Text.ToUpper())).ToList
   }
```

Comment: you need to use the debugger to figure out which object in that statement is null

Comment: Some elements have the Note property null, how could I prevent them from creating an exception for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some elements have the Note property null

check for a null

```
Where(x => x.Nota != null && x.Nota.ToUpper().Contains(TestoSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
```